# Replace content in div after successful ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to replace a content of `<div id="container"></div>` after the ajax function is successful, also without page refresh.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "scripts/process.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        //Whats the code here to replace content in #conatiner div to:
        //<p> Your article was successfully added!</p>
      }
     });
    return false;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "scripts/process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function( returnedData ) {
    $( '#container' ).html( returnedData );
  }
 });
```

also using http://api.jquery.com/load/,

```
$( '#container' ).load( 'scripts/process.php', { your: 'dataHereAsAnObjectWillMakeItUsePost' } );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "context" for an ajax request which then is passed into the `success` handler. In there, you might just call `.html()` to replace the content.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "scripts/process.php",
  data: dataString,
  context: '#container',
  success: function() {
    $(this).html('<p> Your article was successfully added!</p>');
  }
});
```

Ref.:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/html/