# Create a show FormType With Ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I want to create a new form and show it directly in the view when i click into a button,

http://snapplr.com/snap/xbn2

This is my view

Ive already prepared my action in controller, and my new formType

```css
class AttributOptionType extends AbstractType
{
    private $type;
    public function __construct($type){
        $this->type = $type;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', array(
                    'label'     => 'formType.translations',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'name' => array(
                            'label'     => 'Titre',
                            'field_type' => 'text',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'attr'  => array(
                                'class'     => 'form-control input-circle-right'
                            )
                        ),
                        'description' => array(
                            'label'     => 'Titre',
                            'field_type' => 'text',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'attr'  => array(
                                'class'     => 'form-control input-circle-right'
                            )
                        ),
                    )
                ));
        switch ($this->type) {
            case 'radio' || 'checkbox':
                $builder
                    ->add('image', new MediaType(), array(
                        'label'     => 'Image',
                        'attr'      => array(
                            'class'     => 'form-control input-circle-right',
                        ),
                        'required'      => false,
                    ))
                    ->add('code', 'text', array(
                        'label'     => 'Image',
                        'attr'      => array(
                            'class'     => 'form-control input-circle-right',
                        ),
                        'required'      => false,
                    ));
                break;
            
            case 'color':
                $builder
                    ->add('optionValue', 'text', array(
                        'label'     => 'Image',
                        'attr'      => array(
                            'class'     => 'form-control input-circle-right',
                        ),
                        'required'      => false,
                    ));
                break;
        }
    }
```

My action :

```css
public function createOptionAction($type){
        $entity = new AttributOption();
        $form = $this->createForm(new AttributOptionType($type), $entity);

        
    }
```

Switch $type i will create my FormType, so all what i want to do, is to create this form from the view directly using AjaxRequest and display my new form type in the view,

How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this myself, but in theory you can just create a seperate action that returns the form's html. Something like

```
public function createOptionAction($type){
    $entity = new AttributOption();
    $form = $this->createForm(new AttributOptionType($type), $entity);

    return $this->render('AppBundle:AttributOption:form.html.twig', array('form' => $form));
}
```

Of course you have to create the corresponding template that only renders the form, without html or body tags.

Then call the route of that action via ajax from your main view with jQuery or whatever you are using. (I found the ajax stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403953/replace-content-in-div-after-successful-ajax-function), hope it works)

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    $('#yourButton').on('click', function(event){
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{ path('your_route') }}",
        data: dataString,
        success: function( returnedData ) {
            $( '#container' ).html( returnedData );
        }
        });
    }
{% endblock %}
```

Then of course you need an action that handles the submitted form. But that's nothing special there, just do it like with a normal form.

Comment: First thank you for replying,
I approve your solution, but you have to know that i want to create x AttributOptionType 

Look at this picture : http://snapplr.com/snap/yhmc

my function javascript will send the values of select form "type", in each case that will create a new FormType, is that possible ?

Comment: You can generate the form based on the data in the request object. But you have to make sure that the action that handles the submit gets the same form or there will likely be errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have updating my code :

My Ajax Function

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     var id_select = $('#products_productsbundle_attribut_type').val();
      $('.ajaxOption').on('click', function(event){
        $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        data: {'id': id_select},
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "{{ path('admin_products_attribut_optionAdd') }}",
        success: function( returnedData ) {
            $( '.container' ).html( returnedData.form );
        }
        });
    });
     </script>
```

And My action :

```js
public function createOptionAction(){
        $entity = new AttributOption();
        $form = $this->createForm(new AttributOptionType($_POST['id']), $entity);

        $response = new JsonResponse(array(
            'message' => 'Error',
            'form' => $this->renderView('ProductsBundle:Administration:Attribut/form.html.twig',array(
                    'entity' => $entity,
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                )
            )), 400);

        return $response;
    }
```

And this my route :

admin_products_attribut_optionAdd:
    pattern:  /addOption
    defaults: { _controller: "ProductsBundle:BackEnd/Attribut:createOption" }

The error is : 
GET http://ispace/app_dev.php/admin/products/attribut/addOption?id=text 500 (Internal Server Error)m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:4m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ new:1083m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3